# Lambda is deduced to std::function if template has no variadic arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++-2015

```
template<typename ReturnT, typename... ParamT>
void foo(std::function<ReturnT(ParamT...)> callback)
{}

template<typename ReturnT, typename ParamT>
void bar(std::function<ReturnT(ParamT)> callback)
{}

main()
{    
    foo<int, int>([](int x){ return x; });  // no instance of function 
                                            //   template matches argument list
    bar<int, int>([](int x){ return x; });  // OK
}
```

The only difference between *foo* and *bar* is that *foo* has variadic arguments. Somehow the compiler is able to convert the lambda to a std::function in *bar*.

To my understanding, template type deduction doesn't consider type conversions. So shouldn't both fail?

Comment: Depending on use-case and your needs, I suggest you *don't* use `std::function` as argument, and instead look at how the standard library handles callable objects using only a single template argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
template<typename ReturnT, typename... ParamT>
void foo(std::function<ReturnT(ParamT...)> callback)
{}
```

now, `foo<int,int>` is `foo<ReturnT=int, ParamsT starts with {int}>`.

It does not fully specify `ParamT`.  In fact, there is no way to fully specify `ParamT`.

As an incompletely specified template, deduction occurs, and fails.  It doesn't try "what if I just assume the pack doesn't go any further".

You can fix this with:

```
template<typename ReturnT, typename... ParamT>
void foo(block_deduction<std::function<ReturnT(ParamT...)>> callback)
{}
```

where `block_deduction` looks like:

```
template<class T>
struct block_deduction_helper { using type=T; }:
template<class T>
using block_deduction = typename block_deduction_helper<T>::type;
```

now deduction is blocked on `foo`'s first argument.

And your code works.

Of course, if you pass in a `std::function` it will no longer auto-deduce arguments.

Note that deducing the type of a a type erasure type like `std::function` is usually code smell.

Replace both with:

```
template<class F>
void bar(F callback)
{}
```

if you must get arguments, use function traits helpers (there are many on SO).  If you just need return value, there are `std` traits that already work that out.

---

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) you can do this:

```
tempate<class R, class...Args>
void bar( std::function<R(Args...)> f ) {}
template<class F>
void bar( F f ) {
  std::function std_f = std::move(f);
  bar(std_f);
}
```

using the [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) deduction guides feature.

Comment: can you clarify why "deducing the type of a type erasure type like std::function" is usually a code smell?

Comment: Type erasure and type deduction are rough inverses.  Doing both is like taking a `int*const*` and unconditionally dereferencing it. The `&` at call site and unconditional `*` at use site indicate a problem; so is deducing the type to type erase a type to.

Answer (score 10):

You don't have any deduction for the type parameters of `bar`, they are fully specified.

You still have the tail of the pack to deduce in `foo`, and that fails because the lambda isn't a `std::function`.

Comment: Presumably some type deduction happens for the call to bar in the argument type conversion when it tries to find the appropriate std::function constructor. Just not directly to find the right bar.

Comment: @PeterT not *type deduction*, but *conversion*. They are two distinct concepts which happen at different phases of compilation.

Comment: @RichardHodges but during type conversion there's some type deduction happening in the [std::function constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function)