# Type deduction when passing lambda into variadic std::function

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, std-function

I'm trying to retrieve values from a tuple of arrays using type information on the function used for processing them. However, type deduction fails for this case due (in part?) to the need to use an identity struct for the typename of the `std::function`. Is there a way to restore deduction here?

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

class comp_a
{
public:
    static const size_t id = 0;

    int val = 0;
};

class comp_b
{
public:
    static const size_t id = 1;

    int val = 0;
};

class comp_c
{
public:
    static const size_t id = 2;

    int val = 0;
};

template<size_t size, typename ... Cs>
struct storage
{    
    template<typename T> struct identity { using type = T; };

    template<typename ... Ts>
    void get(size_t index, typename identity<std::function<void(Ts& ...)>>::type f)
    {
        f(std::get<Ts::id>(components)[index] ...);
    }

    std::tuple<std::array<Cs, size> ...> components;
};

int32_t main()
{
    storage<20, comp_a, comp_b, comp_c> storage;

    storage.get(2, [](comp_a& a, comp_c& c) {              // Doesn't work
    // storage.get<comp_a, comp_c>(2, [](comp_a& a, comp_c& c) { // Works
        std::cout << a.val << " " << c.val << std::endl;
    });
}
```

I've run across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52850300/lambda-is-deduced-to-stdfunction-if-template-has-no-variadic-arguments) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32555687/variadic-templates-type-deduction-and-stdfunction), which seem similar, but I believe my situation is different because I need the variadic types in order to access their traits when retrieving the desired values. As in those examples, the variadic parameters to the function are treated as void:

```
error: cannot convert 'main()::<lambda(comp_a&, comp_c&)>' to 'storage<20, comp_a, comp_b, comp_c>::identity<std::function<void()> >::type' {aka 'std::function<void()>'}
```

Would a deduction guide be viable in this situation? The type information seems buried a little deep in the type of the `std::function`, and so I'm not sure how I would pull it out in a guide.

A live example is available [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jVxQNwGYuA8ItaZc).

Comment: I don't have an answer to your specific question, but why use the `std::function` at all? Couldn't you get away with using `identity<void(Ts&...)>::type` (or even `void(Ts&...)`?

Comment: Sadly a regular function pointer wouldn't work because AFAIK it rules out any capture inside the lambda (something I'd like to do, though I don't do it in this example). It also seems to fail argument deduction when I try it. Running it through the identity presents the same issue where deduction is blinded to the function parameters.

Comment: one use for an identity type is exactly what you're trying to avoid. It makes your argument non-deducible so that it must be specified in a template type list. So I'm not sure why its there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `std::function` deduction guide trick to pull out the arguments, but you really don't want to *actually create* a `std::function`. You want to stack in lambda-land. `std::function` adds overhead and allocation due to type erasure - but there is nothing you're doing that actually requires the benefits that type erasure provides. It is all loss and no win. **Don't actually make a `std::function`**.

That said, you still of course need the arguments. So you can do this:

```
template <typename T> struct type { };

template <typename F>
void get(size_t index, F f) {
    using function_type = decltype(std::function(f));
    get_impl(index, f, type<function_type>{});
}
```

Basically, we take some callable - and then we deduce a `std::function` from it. That gives us some type. In the specific example in OP, that type is `std::function<void(comp_a&, comp_b&)>`. We then simply forward that type through to a different function - as an empty object. No overhead. To repeat, we're not actually creating a `std::function` - we're just passing its type around.

That other function can take advantage of knowing what `std::function` knows:

```
template <typename T> using uncvref_t = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;

template <typename F, typename R, typename... Args>
void get_impl(size_t index, F f, type_t<std::function<R(Args...)>>) {
    f(std::get<uncvref_t<Args>::id>(components)[index] ...);
}
```

You need the `uncvref_t` there to handle the case where `Args` may or may not be a reference or *cv*-qualified.

Now, this won't work for *any* callable. If you pass in a generic lambda, deducing `std::function` will fail for it. But then... that couldn't work anyway, so it doesn't seem like a big loss?

Comment: [Surprised and impressed at how well this optimizes.](https://godbolt.org/z/jE92_o) Would you mind explaining to me what role `type<T>` serves here and why it's necessary?

Comment: @rtek We need the type of the `std::function` to deduce to get the arguments, but we don't want to make an object of that type. `type<T>` is just a way to pass types around

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the `identity` struct is for but removing it gives a clearer error message (template deduction failed).

The compiler is unable to derive the `std::function` type from the lambda. To prove this the following does compile:

```
storage.get(2, std::function<void(comp_a& a, comp_c& c)>([](comp_a& a, comp_c& c) {              // Doesn't work
    std::cout << a.val << " " << c.val << std::endl;
}));
```

So to make it work we just need to give the compiler a helping hand deriving the types. Borrowing from http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/223816/ the following works:

```
namespace detail
{
    template < typename T > struct deduce_type;

    template < typename RETURN_TYPE, typename CLASS_TYPE, typename... ARGS >
    struct deduce_type< RETURN_TYPE(CLASS_TYPE::*)(ARGS...) const >
    {
        using type = std::function< RETURN_TYPE(ARGS...) >;
    };
}

template<size_t size, typename ... Cs>
struct storage
{
    template<typename ... Ts>
    void get(size_t index, typename std::function<void(Ts& ...)> f)
    {
        f(std::get<Ts::id>(components)[index] ...);
    }

    template<typename Lambda>
    void get(size_t index, Lambda l)
    {
        get( index, typename detail::deduce_type< decltype( &Lambda::operator() ) >::type( l ) );
    }

    std::tuple<std::array<Cs, size> ...> components;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You tagged C++17, so you can use the `std::function`'s deduction guides

So, as suggested by Alan Birtles, you can receive the lambda as a simple type, convert it to a `std::function` (deduction guides) and deduce the type of the arguments.

Something as

```
template<size_t size, typename ... Cs>
struct storage
{    
    template<typename ... Ts>
    void get(size_t index, std::function<void(Ts& ...)> f)
    { f(std::get<Ts::id>(components)[index] ...); }

    template <typename F>
    void get(size_t index, F f)
    { get(index, std::function{f}); }

    std::tuple<std::array<Cs, size> ...> components;
};
```

Comment: Even `std::remove_cv_t<Ts>::id`.

Comment: @Jarod42 - ehmmm... why? I mean: what's can going wrong without it?

Comment: To handle `std::function<void(const Ta&, Tb&)>`.